# How to stop Bootstrap carousel from autosliding?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have built a bootstrap video carousel. It is working just fine but, the only problem I have is the carousel keeps sliding to the next slide after 5 seconds. How do I make it stop autosliding and only slide when the user clicks on the left or right arrows? I have pasted the code below.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause=hover>
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay muted id="homevid">
                            <source src="C:\Development Software\Sample Website\videos\Michael Vick 88 yard touchdown pass to DeSean Jackson.mp4" />
                        </video>
                    </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay muted id="homevid">
                        <source src="C:\Development Software\Sample Website\videos\Vick to Jeremy Maclin for 50 Yard TD.mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay muted id="homevid">
                        <source src="C:\Development Software\Sample Website\videos\Michael Vick Scramble Plays vs Rams 2011.mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 144):

By adding `data-interval="false"`

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" >
```

From the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage)

> Option - Interval -  ..If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

## 2021 Update

In Bootstrap 5 it is `data-bs-interval="false"`

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
```

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#options)

Comment: One info for Angular guys who is using `ngb-carousel` : just modify as follows: 

`<ngb-carousel data-interval="false"  ...>`

Comment: This will not work for automatic corousel of bootstrap. it will work for manual placing of code for bootstrap corousel

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks :)

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla cobble, it does work for the auto scroll!

Comment: Thanks for the 2021 update. It is not fun to see continuous sliding while developing the page.

Comment: For me removing `data-ride="carousel"` was enough (Bootstrap 3.x). Then start it with `$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');`

Comment: in version 5.2 it does not work

Answer (score 37):

There are two ways.

## 1.

#### Update 2022: Bootstrap 5.x

In your HTML code, you need to use **data-bs-interval="false"**

```html
<div id="your-carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false">
</div>
```

#### Bootstrap 4.x

In your HTML code, you need to use **data-interval="false"**

```html
<div id="your-carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
</div>
```

## 2.

If you want to do with the help of Jquery then you need to add.

```js
// document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Event for pushed the video
    $('#your-carousel-id').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false
    });
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the Javascript part. I had the `data-interval="false"` but it wasn't working because somewhere in my code was the `$("#carousel-id").carousel()`. I didn't realize that leaving `carousel()` with no params was activating it.

Answer (score 11):

To stop the autoplay is by just removing the attribute **data-ride=”carousel”** from the htmlcode

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">....</div>
```

There is another way to stop autoplay just add below code in your js file

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause'); 
});
```

Comment: Then to start it, use `$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');`

Answer (score 5):

Paste this code on your custom Javascript file.

$('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    });

Answer (score 3):

There is an update on bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/

> data-bs-interval="false"

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

In react-bootstrap in order to stop cycling you have to use

```
<Carousel interval={null}>
   ...
</Carousel>
```

Answer (score 2):

for bootstrap v5.2:
Just remove "data-bs-ride:carousel" part from the div tag having "carousel slide" in order to stop the auto-slide

Answer (score 0):

By adding **data-interval="false"** and removing **data-ride="carousel"** to the carousel id or class

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on why `data-bs-ride=false` does not work for this and i understand it now.

In version 5.0 and 5.1, notice in documentation under options subsection it says

> Autoplays the carousel after the user manually cycles the first item. If set to 'carousel', autoplays the carousel on load.

This just means that `data-bs-ride=false`, `data-bs-ride=true` or `data-ride="carousel"` it will still auto slide so we have to use

> `data-interval="false"` and remove `data-ride="carousel"`

But in version 5.2 the documentation says that

> If set to true, autoplays the carousel after the user manually cycles the first item. If set to "carousel", autoplays the carousel on load.

So, we can stop the autoplay by just using `data-bs-ride=false` or just removing `data-bs-ride` tag bc it is by default false.