# Turn off auto-slide in tailwind carousel

Tags: carousel, tailwind-css

How do I turn off a carousel in tailwind elements from auto-sliding? It seems to be the default setting, but I can't find any documentation on how to turn it off.
I've used this example on the tailwind elements page: https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/

I've used the data-interval="false" attribute, but it appears to stop autosliding the first time, but after manually sliding by interacting with the slider buttons, it starts autosliding again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue with the carousel, and I noticed that based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133618/how-to-stop-bootstrap-carousel-from-autosliding), you need to use data-bs-interval="false" instead for Bootstrap 5.x which Tailwind Elements uses. I've tried this out and it seems to stop the carousel from sliding automatically.